# iphone development: how to track GLKViewController with GoogleAnalytics?

Tags: objective-c, ios, opengl-es, google-analytics, glkit

In my iPhone app I use Open GL GLKViewController. It is a simple game. I want to track the game with GoogleAnalytics but it offers to change

```
@interface AboutViewController : UIViewController
```

with this

```
#import "GAITrackedViewController.h"

@interface AboutViewController : GAITrackedViewController
```

But in my case, I use GLKViewController so I cant just remove it and put GAITrackedViewController. Is there a way to track it with google analytics?

```
@interface GameViewController : GLKViewController <UIAccelerometerDelegate>
{
.....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's an old question this, but for the next person who is going to look for the same answer here it is:

You can do this manually:

```
// May return nil if a tracker has not already been initialized with a
// property ID.
id tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] defaultTracker];

// This screen name value will remain set on the tracker and sent with
// hits until it is set to a new value or to nil.
[tracker set:kGAIScreenName value:@"Home Screen"];

[tracker send:[[GAIDictionaryBuilder createAppView] build]];
```